# Why do you echo results of php functions to get them back to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, return, echo

I call a php function using jquery

```
$.get("tableau_trusted.php",{username:$("#username").val(),password:$("#password").val()},function(data){
                    alert(data);
            });
```

Why do I return the result from the php file like this:

```
 echo "http://$server/trusted/$ticket/$view_url?$params";
```

Instead of:

```
 return "http://$server/trusted/$ticket/$view_url?$params";
```

I know I should use POST with the password, I'm just playing around for now.

Thanks!

Comment: Because that's how PHP works? Your jQuery is _not_ calling a PHP function, it is making an http request for 'tableau_trusted.php'. The client-side code doesn't know or care what happens inside 'tableau_trusted.php', it just wants an http response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Javascript and PHP can only communicate via HTTP. The PHP script receives an HTTP request, which is just a bunch of text. It sends back a reply, which is also just a bunch of text. The way to *output* this bunch of text is by `echo`ing it to the standard output. An AJAX request/response is exactly the same as any other normal webpage you'd write using PHP.